# How to grab all the issues inside a jira structureboard using REST api

Tags: rest, jira-rest-api, jira-agile

I have been researching Jira REST api in order to grab all the test cases inside my structures but I haven't had any luck. The closes I have been to getting inside a structure is using the URL `$baseUrl/rest/structure/2.0/structure`. From there I tried to manipulate the url into giving me all the information about a specific structure.
For example, I used `$baseUrl/rest/structure/2.0/structure/$id` but I only got back

```
{"id":135,"name":"TEST PLAN 1","description":""}
```

There is hardly any information in this REST api call. IS there a way to have it list out all the issue keys(test cases) in the structure i pick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information Regarding JIRA Structure REST API is posted here https://wiki.almworks.com/display/structure/Forest+Resource